# Laravel form isn't subbmitting

Tags: php, laravel, forms

I have a Laravel form that isn't submitting? It's hitting a post method, I can see the data in the payload, but it will not submit through the form.

It's working perfectly when I'm testing it through postman. What happens when I sumbit in the browser is that the page refreshed. If I try and return the data submitted instead of posting it, it still refresh the page. Any advice

This is the form

```
<form method="POST" action="/blog/create">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Cover Image</label>
                    <input type="file" name="image_name" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Title</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" id="title" placeholder="Title">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Tags</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tags" id="title" placeholder="Title">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Example textarea</label>
                  <textarea class="form-control" name="body" id="summernote" rows="3"></textarea>
                </div>

                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
              </form>
```

This is the submit method

```
public function store(CreateBlogRequest $createBlogRequest, PhotoRequest $photoRequest)
    {
        $user = User::find(1);
        // $user = auth()->user();

        $post = $user->posts()->create($createBlogRequest->only(['title', 'body']));
        $this->handleTags($post, $createBlogRequest->tags);
        $this->handleImage($post, $photoRequest);

        return $post;

    }

    public function handleTags(Post $post, $tags)
    {
        $tagsNames = explode(',', $tags);

        $tags = [];

        foreach($tagsNames as $tagName){
            $tag = trim($tagName);
            array_push($tags, $tag);
        }
        foreach($tags as $tagName){
            Tag::firstOrCreate(['post_id' => $post->id, 'tag_name' => $tagName])->save();
        }
    }

    public function handleImage(Post $post, $photoRequest) 
    {
        $image_name = $photoRequest->file('image_name')->getRealPath();;
        Cloudder::upload($image_name, null);
        $result = Cloudder::getResult();
        $photo = $post->photo()->create(['url' => $result['url'], 'public_id' => $result['public_id']]);
    }
```

These are the routes

//Backend Posts

```
Route::get('/dashboard', 'Backend\DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard.index');
Route::get('/blog/create', 'Backend\DashboardController@create')->name('post.create');
Route::post('/blog/create', 'PostController@store')->name('post.store');
```

Any idea why this is not submitting?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't return the request from the controller and you're returned back without an exception, then most likely there is a validation error. Try dumping validation errors in the view.

Put this above your form:

```
@if ($errors->any())
    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
        {{ $error }}
    @endforeach
@endif
```

or try

```
{{ dd($errors->all() }}
```

Answer (score 0):

The form also needs the following attribute: `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. It specifies which content-type to use when submitting the form.
Without this attribute, the file upload will not work.

Example: `<form method="POST" action="/blog/create" enctype="multipart/form-data">`